# Append a variable into a variable

Tags: python

I am bit new to python. This may be a simple question but had to asked. Help much appreciated.

This is what I am doing in my below code.

```
sysLst = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: ')).upper().strip()
nsysLst1="|".join(["^" + sysList_t + "$" for sysList_t in sysLst.split('|')])
nsysLst = nsysLst1.replace("^SCALE$", "PRIMARY-SCALE1|PRIMARY-SCALE2|AUXVM-SCALE1|AUXVM-SCALE2")
print nsysLst
if "ALL" in nsysLst:
        nsysLst = "PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE"
```

When I run above code and give the input as PRIMARY, I get the result as :

```
Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: PRIMARY
^PRIMARY$
```

And if give the input as SCALE, I get the output:

```
Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: SCALE
PRIMARY-SCALE1|PRIMARY-SCALE2|AUXVM-SCALE1|AUXVM-SCALE2
```

---

Now my question is when I give the input 'ALL' how can I change the 'SCALE' option in output with 'nsysLst'.

As of now I am getting below output while giving 'ALL' input:

```
Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: ALL
^ALL$
```

but my for 'ALL' input my intended output should be :

```
Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: ALL
^PRIMARY$|^PRIMARY-HA1$|^SECONDARY$|^SECONDARY-HA1$|^PRIMARY-SCALE1$|^PRIMARY-SCALE2$|^AUXVM-SCALE1$|^AUXVM-SCALE2$
```

Please let me know how can I get this.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. Could you try to shorten the question to include only the bare minimum of necessary code (removing any logic that *does* work as you expect already)?

Comment: Also, take a close look at your order of operations. If you're handling ALL as a special case, surely you want to do that **before** you then split and re-join the contents? And making changes **after** you already printed your output makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sysLst = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: ')).upper().strip()
if "ALL" in sysLst:
    nsysLst1 = "PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|^SCALE$"
    nsysLst = nsysLst1.replace("^SCALE$", "PRIMARY-SCALE1|PRIMARY-SCALE2|AUXVM-SCALE1|AUXVM-SCALE2")
    output="|".join(["^" + sysList_t + "$" for sysList_t in nsysLst.split('|')])
else:    
    nsysLst1="|".join(["^" + sysList_t + "$" for sysList_t in sysLst.split('|')])
    output = nsysLst1.replace("^SCALE$", "PRIMARY-SCALE1|PRIMARY-SCALE2|AUXVM-SCALE1|AUXVM-SCALE2")
print output
```

Comment: I'd think you'd want the split-and-rejoin to be unconditional, not in the `else` clause, since the OP says that they want the `^`s and `$`s on *every* individual item in that case (shown in their "intended output" section).

Comment: @rdRahul Thanks Rahul here if I give the 'ALL' Input I am getting the output as:
`Enter pipe separated list of items [PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE|ALL]: all
PRIMARY|PRIMARY-HA1|SECONDARY|SECONDARY-HA1|SCALE`
here you can see 'SCALE' is coming as it is. But I need to replace it with the strings which is assigned in 'nsysLst' variable in your code.

Comment: @rdRahul Thank you so much Rahul. This is what I wanted. I got your logic as well. You are the jam.